# Execute some actions when the transaction fails in laravel 10

Tags: laravel, database, transactions

Exists some way to do some actions after a transaction fails in laravel?, I know it's possible to use a try/catch, but inside of the transaction are other delegate instructions that alredy utilizes try/catch statement.

```
DB::transaction(function () {
    $this->otherService->Create($data);
});
  
class OtherService
{
    public function Create(){
      try{
       //Some database operations
      }catch(Exception $e){

      }
    }
}
```

I need help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle failed transactions without using a `try/catch block` directly around the transaction, you can leverage database events and observers. Laravel provides a `TransactionCommitted` and `TransactionRolledBack` event that you can listen to and perform actions upon. This avoids placing a try/catch block directly around your transaction code.

Create an observer that listens to the `TransactionRolledBack` event:

```
php artisan make:observer TransactionFailedObserver --queued
```

Inside the `TransactionFailedObserver` class, handle the rollback event:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Events\TransactionRolledBack;

class TransactionFailedObserver
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    public function failed(TransactionRolledBack $event)
    {
        // Logic to execute when a transaction fails
        // You can add your desired actions here, such as logging or additional operations
        
        // Example: Log the exception
        logger()->error('Transaction failed: ' . $event->exception->getMessage());
        
        // Example: Rollback another related action
        // Your code here...
    }
}
```

Register the observer in the `EventServiceProvider`:

```
protected $listen = [
    'Illuminate\Database\Events\TransactionRolledBack' => [
        'App\Observers\TransactionFailedObserver@failed',
    ],
];
```

Trigger the transaction without a `try/catch block`:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

DB::transaction(function () use ($data) {
    $this->otherService->create($data);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but this always will be execute when a transaction fail, in any part of the code, it´s true?. I need do some actions only if that specific transaction fails.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using [Manual Transactions](https://laravel.com/docs/database#manually-using-transactions):

```php
class OtherService
{
    public function create($data)
    {
        try {
            DB::beginTransaction();

            // Some database operations

            // If everything is successful, commit the transaction
            DB::commit();
        } catch (\Throwable $e) {
            // Something went wrong, rollback the transaction
            DB::rollBack();

            // Handle the exception or log it
            // You can also rethrow the exception if needed
            throw $e;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but i want to avoid have a try/cath statement inside another.

Comment: You don't need to do that. In fact, you don't even need to worry about the transaction when calling the create method. You'd do just `$this->otherService->create($data);` and how it handles the creation is encapsulated within the create function. You can also move the try catch out of the create function along with the transaction if you want. Depends on your use case.